# A piece preventing white king from occupying a square can't move for uncovering check on black king can the first king occupy said square anyway?

Tags: rules

For instance
Black king is on g8
black light coloured bishop is on g6
white queen is on g5
black rook on d6 and black pawn on c3 are checking White king on d2
white king captures black pawn on c3
black rook moves to d3 checking king
Shouldn't white king be able to capture black rook on d3 because black bishop on g6
is prevented from attacking anyway?